# how to fix the problem where useSWR based on state, but state does not initialize on reload and so unnecessary call is made to API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, swr

I have a component that calls useSWR based on state
The state defaulted to false on load and set to true on button click.
It works well until component re renders with different props. The state is now true (does not initialize to false) and so useSWR is called unnecessarily. How Can I avoid that?

```
    // does not set to false on rerender- expected
    const [showComp, setShowComp] = useState(false)
    
    // calls useSWR on rerender before handleClick- how to fix this?
    const { data, isValidating, isLoading } = useSWR(showComp ? url : null)

    function onHandleClick() {
        setShowComp(true)
     }
```